# Tether USDT raw transaction unsigned

Tags: transactions, raw-transaction, tether

I'm not using omnicore by RPC calls, I dont want to put a server up and make those RPC calls, I want to make a simple transaction on the TetherUS(USDT) network, this is my code:

```
const getUnsignedTransaction = async (data) => {
  let { pubKey, fromAddr, toAddr, amount, fee, testnet } = data;
  let params = new URLSearchParams;
  params.append('transaction_version',1);
  params.append('currency_identifier',31);
  params.append('fee',fee);
  params.append('testnet',testnet);
  params.append('pubkey',pubKey);
  params.append('amount_to_transfer',amount);
  params.append('transaction_from',fromAddr);
  params.append('transaction_to',toAddr);
  return await Axios.post('/v1/transaction/getunsigned/0', params);
}
```

When I call this function above

```
  let a = await getUnsignedTransaction({
    amount:    '0.00001',
    fee:       '0.00005',
    testnet:   false,
    toAddr:    '1KH34S5mAmgAzu3mJAqrS3wjP15qYKZQXx',
    fromAddr:  '17UrxYAAF5WkjtFKeuZ2S7ojDWoJY2LunF',
 pubKey:'03f26647f3bbf4566318d00e2438036be0f1a68ee5deea604be6fa6cad68349888',
  }).then(e => e.data);
  console.log(a);
```

I got this response:

```
{ sourceScript:
   'OP_DUP OP_HASH160 4715b028de4327f5f87915d89d1d074db3f03992 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG',
  status: 200,
  unsignedhex:
   '0100000001131184d4a10bbf1acef3cb137d37ecc8f36cb3da208c9ebe86fb988821d532b40100000000ffffffff034d160000000000001976a9144715b028de4327f5f87915d89d1d074db3f0399288ac22020000000000001976a914c87aa36f1402052ef87ea433c2fa252ae9a9794988ac0000000000000000166a146f6d6e69000000000000001f00000000000003e800000000' }
```

Now here is the question: How can I make this **unsigned raw transaction** an valid transaction to the Tether network and so, broadcast this **signed raw transaction**

This is the blockexplorer I'm using: https://api.omniexplorer.info/#request-v1-transaction-pushtx

---

## Code solution

As the @Raghav_Sood chosen answer, I had to use `bitconjs-lib` to wrap this transaction and to sign it.

For those who wanna see in the future how I made the transaction, was kinda this:

```
let tx  = bitcoinjs.Transaction.fromHex(raw);
let txb = bitcoinjs.TransactionBuilder.fromTransaction(tx);
txb.sign(0, keyPair)
let raw = txb.build().toHex();

let d = await pushtx(raw).then(e => e.data);
```

function `pushtx`

```
async function pushtx(raw) {
  let params = new URLSearchParams;
  params.append('signedTransaction',raw);
  return await Axios.post('/v1/transaction/pushtx/',params);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only omni-specific thing in Omni/Tether txs is the OP RETURN, and a small dust output to the address you are sending the funds to. Both of these seem to check out in your tx (I'm assuming you're sending to `1KH34S5mAmgAzu3mJAqrS3wjP15qYKZQXx`).

You should be able to just use the regular Bitcoind signing functionality (or whatever library you are using's wrapper of it). They don't require any special signatures.

Comment: https://omniexplorer.info/search/57af554e02ed572f49493c7c5a1cce7621c981e1f9a52cc1ec808fb229d002d5

Comment: I was trying that, but in a different way, thanks.

Comment: I'll put the code later on, in the question.